# How do I register a 32-bit out-proc ATL COM server to make it available from 64-bit programs?

Tags: visual-c++, com, registry, atl

We have a 32-bit ATL out-proc COM server. In order to register itself in the registry it calls `CComModule::UpdateRegistryFromResource()` and passes an id of a .rgs file compiled into the resources of the same executable.

Works great on 32-bit systems, but not on 64-bit ones. Obviously when a 32-bit .exe runs on a 64-bit Windows its registry accesses are redirected and so it registers itself in "32-bit HKCR" and so 64-bit programs don't see its registration.

How do I register the same out-proc server in the 64-bit HKCR the cheapeast and most reliable way?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell/remember you don't actually have to do anything special.

I have checked a 32-bit ATL COM EXE server which I wrote specifically to be called from 64-bit code ( http://www.pretentiousname.com/adobe_pdf_x64_fix/index.html ) and the registration code is completely boilerplate (unless I forgot and today cannot see something I had to change).

Unless the code on the 64-bit side calling CoCreateInstance(Ex) is specifically passing CLSCTX_ACTIVATE_64_BIT_SERVER, COM should automatically check the 32-bit registry if needed. (Even if CLSCTX_ACTIVATE_64_BIT_SERVER is passed it may still do. MSDN isn't entirely clear if that flag is a preference or a requirement. I'm assuming it isn't being passed anyway.)

Perhaps the problem isn't how the COM server is registered but something else. Or perhaps there is a broken 64-bit version of the server registered, maybe from earlier in development/testing, which is being chosen over the 32-bit server and failing?

By the way, there are differences in which parts of the registry are 32/64-bit split on Windows 7 vs earlier OS versions, but I know from experience that you don't need to do anything special on Vista, Windows 7 and Server 2008 R2. I haven't personally tested on other OS versions (e.g. XPx64).

Comment: Do you just call something like CComModule::RegisterServer()?